# Multiple Current Requests to File System folder to Process Files C# XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, windows-services

I have a folder that exists on the file system that has a lot of XML files in it. Let's say 10,000.

I have multiple (5) Windows Services checking that folder every 30 seconds and process files simultaneously. I'm trying to write the service process code smart enough so that it can handle the concurrent requests for processing.

However it's getting hung up sometimes on a couple of files.

```
E[The process cannot access the file '...' because it is being used by another process.]
```

I see the error above logged on about 1% of the files during processing. What can I do to improve the following code to prevent this?

```
class Program
{
    private static string _instanceGuid;
    static string InstanceGuid
    {
        get
        {
            if(_instanceGuid == null)
            {
                _instanceGuid =  Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            }
            return _instanceGuid;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] sourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles("c\\temp\\source\\*.xml")
                                       .OrderBy(d => new FileInfo(d).CreationTime).ToArray();

        foreach (string file in sourceFiles)
        {
            var newFileName = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                // first we'll rename in this way try and 
                // i would think it should throw an exception and move on to the next file. an exception being thrown means that file should already be processing by another service. 

                newFileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", file, InstanceGuid);
                File.Move(file, newFileName);

                var xml = string.Empty;
                using (var s = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                using (var tr = new StreamReader(s))
                {
                    xml = tr.ReadToEnd();
                }

                // at this point we have a valid XML save to db
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                // continue onto next source file
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // log error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "FileShare.None" to "FileShare.Read" on the following line:

```
            using (var s = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hey thanks for the response but this isn't working. I would definitely think we'd want FileShare to be NONE

Comment: You can synchronize the services by a single central service. By a central service you can prevent different services from parallel accesses to same file. Alternatively you can deterministically divide the files into some foreign sets and assign each of them to a different service.